# Coinbase trasnfer between accounts

Tags: php, curl

I have created **OAuth2** Applications and successfully connected into it using this instructions https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/integrating and with the next permissions **wallet:user:read, wallet:transactions:transfer wallet:accounts:read** and got access token.

Then I have got my user and account's info using https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user , https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts links without problems, but when I try to make transaction between two accounts it always returns me the next

```
[errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => service_unavailable
                    [message] => It looks like we encountered a problem. Sorry for the trouble!
                )

)
```

I didn't find description about these errors in documentation, what does it mean? where is the problem?

My curl request is the same as in documentation https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#transfer-money-between-accounts but additionally with and description fileds

```
url https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/2bbf394c-193b-5b2a-9155-3b4732659ede/transactions
  -X POST
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c'
  -d '{
    "type": "transfer",
    "to": "58542935-67b5-56e1-a3f9-42686e07fa40",
    "currency":"BTC",   
    "description":"my first coins"
    "amount": "0.00001"
  }'
```

Comment: You might need to contact them. "service_unavailable" usually means there's either something wrong or restricted on their side.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have send a message to support, I hope they will answer soon.